# Send 8-bit integers over serial to Arduino

Tags: python, c, parsing, arduino, pyserial

I created a music visualizer and I want to send three 8-bit integers (0-255) over serial to an Arduino using Python's `pyserial` library.

I have a text file called `rgb.txt` on my computer which has the data: `8,255,255`. I am sending the data over serial with this code:

```
import serial, time
arduino = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600, timeout=.1)
time.sleep(2) #give the connection a second to settle

while True:
    with open("rgb.txt") as f:
        rgb = f.read().strip("\n")
    arduino.write(rgb.encode("ASCII"))

    data = arduino.readline()
    if data:
        try:
            print(data.decode('ASCII').strip("\r").strip("\n")) # (better to do .read() in the long run for this reason
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            pass
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

And I'm receiving it with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int r = A0;
int g = A1;
int b = A2;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  analogWrite(r, 255); delay(333); analogWrite(r, 0);
  analogWrite(g, 255); delay(333); analogWrite(g, 0);
  analogWrite(b, 255); delay(334); analogWrite(b, 0);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    char data = Serial.read();
    char str[2];
    str[0] = data;
    str[1] = '\0';
    Serial.println(str);
  }
}
```

The output I am getting is:

```
8
,
2
5
5
,
2
5
5
```

How can I parse it so I receive:

```
8
255
255
```

And preferably in 3 different variables (`r` `g` `b`).

Comment: What terminal emulator are you using?  (teraterm, puTTY, ...?)

Comment: @ryyker What do you mean? I'm just using the Arduino IDE to write the C code and using just a normal python interpreter for the python.

Comment: Is it possible that the statement:  `rgb = f.read().strip("\n")` should be: `rgb = f.read().strip('\n')` ?

Comment: @ryyker No, 1) there is no newlines in the file I just put that there to  be safe and 2) I tested that.

Comment: Instead of Serial.read() try `Serial.parseInt()` - it will read multiple digits and return the value. It does what all the low-level hand-made solutions below do, and it's tested and supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do now is read a `char`, turn it into a CString `str`, and then you `println()` it before you go on to the next `char`.

You could probably stick the bytes together the way you want from what you got, but it is easier to read the received bytes into a buffer and split the result:

Send the RGB values from Python separated with commas and with a `'\n'` on the end, and then on the Arduino do something like this (untested, but you get the idea):

```cpp
void loop() {
  static char buffer[12];
  static uint8_t rgb[3];

  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    Serial.readBytesUntil('\n', buffer, 12);
    int i = 0;
    char *p = strtok(buffer, ",");
    while (p) {
      rgb[i++] = (uint8_t)atoi(p);
      p = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }
    // You now have uint8s in rgb[]
    Serial.println(rgb[0]);
    Serial.println(rgb[1]);
    Serial.println(rgb[2]); 
  }
}
```

Note: no checks and error handling in this code.

There are no doubt prettier ways, but this came to mind first and I think it will work. It could also be done using a String object, but I try to avoid those.

For the code in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65359904/12570891) to work, some things need to be added (but I haven't tested if these additions are enough):

```cpp
void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    char data = Serial.read();
    if (data < '0' || data > '9')
      rgbIndex++;
    else
      rgb[rgbIndex] = rgb[rgbIndex] * 10 + (data - 48);
    if (rgbIndex == 3) {
      // You now have uint_8s in rgb[]
      Serial.println(rgb[0]);
      Serial.println(rgb[1]);
      Serial.println(rgb[2]);
      rgbIndex = 0;
      for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
        rgb[i] = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Note that converting what you read from the file to chars or integers on the Python side and simply sending three bytes would greatly simplify things on the Arduino side.

Comment: Here's a little snippet of the output I got from this code at sending it 0.1 time /second:
255
246
0
-6898
0
-6898
0
-6898
0
Now It works fine at like one time per 3 seconds but that is just not fast enough for me.

Comment: I doubt that the Arduino code is too slow; it is flying along at a throttled 20 RGB sets a second here, and could be faster. Try upping the baudrate to 115200Bd on both ends and see what happens.

Comment: On the top answer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65361590/14818802 it is super close to working I just needed to add a 4th integer for some reason. the issue with it is though is that when I analogWrite the first or second integer the RGB light decides to go crazy and change colors like 50 times per second when it is being sent the same numbers but this only happens when it's above 99.

Comment: Are you sending a '\n' at the end of the three RGB values from the Python code? Are all three values you send <= 255? I made a small change to the code, BTW, please check if the values you receive are OK.

Comment: I had each value being sent set to 200 so its sending "200,200,200" to the arduino I got this output:
200
200
200
200
210
0
200
52
0
200
8
200
8
0
200
8
2
0

Comment: I am not sending any newlines or "\n"s and correct no value will be bigger than 255. I also just tested all of the code on this page and nothing worked. :\

Comment: You need to send "200,200,200\n" from Python. Don't strip the '\n', and add it if it isn't there. The '\n' is important; it tells the Arduino when a complete set of data has arrived.

Comment: "I would send the 3 bytes in one go from Python" There is no other way. With serial connection, it is all one go - it's a stream with no inherent correlation between how the sender writes to it, and how the receiver reads from it. If you want packets, you need packet delimiters such a line endings, and then the reader has to accumulate a packet until it detects a delimiter, and only then process it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have always a ',' character, you can convert it to int.

```
uint8_t rgb[3] = {0,0,0};
uint8_t rgbIndex = 0;

void loop() {
  if(Serial.available() > 0) {
    char data = Serial.read();
    if(data < '0' || data > '9')
      rgbIndex++;
    else
      rgb[rgbIndex] = rgb[rgbIndex] * 10 + (data - '0');
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know If I'm just doing it wrong but I used your code and then did:
Serial.println(rgb[rgbIndex]); and that is just printing numbers which I got no clue what they mean I also tried Serial.println(rgbIndex); which just seemed to count up, I also tried Serial.println(data); and that just gave me the same output I was getting. am I doing something wrong with your code or what?

Comment: It isn't the entire solution. You need to reset rgbindex and get the rgb once index is 3.

Answer (score 0):

Arduino Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int r = A0;
int g = A1;
int b = A2;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  analogWrite(r, 255); delay(333); analogWrite(r, 0);
  analogWrite(g, 255); delay(333); analogWrite(g, 0);
  analogWrite(b, 255); delay(334); analogWrite(b, 0);
}
void loop() {
  static char buffer[12];
  static uint8_t rgb[3];

  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    Serial.readBytesUntil('\n', buffer, 12);
    int i = 0;
    char *p = strtok(buffer, ",");
    while (p) {
      rgb[i++] = (uint8_t)atoi(p);
      p = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }
    // You now have uint8s in rgb[]
    analogWrite(A0, rgb[0]);
    analogWrite(A1, rgb[1]);
    analogWrite(A2, rgb[2]); 
    Serial.println(rgb[0]);
    Serial.println(rgb[1]);
    Serial.println(rgb[2]);
  }
}
```

Python Code:

```
import serial, time
def run():
    arduino = serial.Serial('COM3', 115200, timeout=.1)
    time.sleep(2) #give the connection a second to settle

    while True:
        with open("rgb.txt") as f:
            rgb = f.read()
            rgb += "\n"
        arduino.write(rgb.encode("ASCII"))

        data = arduino.readline()
        if data:
            try:
                print(data.decode('ASCII').strip("\r").strip("\n")) # (better to do .read() in the long run for this reason
            except UnicodeDecodeError:
                pass
        time.sleep(0.1)
while True:
    try:
        run()
    except serial.serialutil.SerialTimeoutException:
        print("Is your com port correct?")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original code is almost correct.

You just need to change the format a little bit to synchronise to newline characters.

## Python Code

```py
import serial, time
arduino = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600, timeout=.1)
time.sleep(2) #give the connection a second to settle

while True:
    with open("rgb.txt") as f:
        rgb = f.read()
        rgb = rgb + '\n'  # Add a newline character after the RGB values to aid sychronisation in the Arduino code.
    arduino.write(rgb.encode("ASCII"))

    data = arduino.readline()
    if data:
        try:
             print(data.decode('ASCII').strip("\r").strip("\n"))
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            pass
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

## Arduino Code

I've used `sscanf()` to read the 3 integers from the buffer because it returns a count of the number of items it successfully scanned into variables. I've also added some `#defines` to make it more readable and maintainable.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

#define PORT_R A0
#define PORT_G A1
#define PORT_B A2

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  analogWrite(PORT_R, 255); delay(333); analogWrite(PORT_R, 0);
  analogWrite(PORT_G, 255); delay(333); analogWrite(PORT_G, 0);
  analogWrite(PORT_B, 255); delay(334); analogWrite(PORT_B, 0);
}

void loop()
{
  uint8_t r, g, b;
  if (ReadRGB(r, g, b))
  {
    analogWrite(PORT_R, r);
    analogWrite(PORT_G, g);
    analogWrite(PORT_B, b);
    Serial.println(r);
    Serial.println(g);
    Serial.println(b);
  }
}

bool ReadRGB(uint8_t &r, uint8_t &g, uint8_t &b)
{
  if (Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    const int LENGTH = 13;  // nnn,nnn,nnn\r\0
    char buffer[LENGTH];
    size_t count = Serial.readBytesUntil('\n', buffer, LENGTH - 1);  // Allow room for NULL terminator.
    buffer[count] = 0;  // Place the NULL terminator after the last character that was read.
    int i = sscanf(buffer, "%d,%d,%d", &r, &g, &b);
    return i == 3;  // Notify whether we successfully read 3 integers.
  }
  return false;
}
```

Regarding [`Serial.parseInt()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/parseint/), it doesn't notify when it times out. Instead, it simply returns 0, which is a valid value, so the caller has no idea whether this was due to a timeout.

The same issue exists with [`Serial.readBytesUntil()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/readbytesuntil/) because it doesn't notify the caller whether the returned byte count is the result of encountering the search character or enduring a timeout. What if `255,255,25` was received due to a timeout caused by a communication error instead of the expected `255,255,255`? The caller would be unaware.

Compare with the robust methodology of [`int.TryParse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse/) in C#.NET which returns a `bool` to indicate success/failure and passes the parsed `int` by reference.

## More Robust Arduino Code

To overcome the issues of `Serial.parseInt()` and `Serial.readBytesUntil()` timing out without returning an error code when the serial input buffer is empty, it's possible to use a [non-blocking algorithm algorithm](https://majenko.co.uk/blog/reading-serial-arduino), something like this which reads one character per `loop()` until it reaches a newline character before scanning the buffer for 3 integers:

```cpp
#define PORT_R A0
#define PORT_G A1
#define PORT_B A2

const int LENGTH = 12;  // nnn,nnn,nnn\0
char buffer[LENGTH];

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("setup()");
  analogWrite(PORT_R, 255); delay(333); analogWrite(PORT_R, 0);
  analogWrite(PORT_G, 255); delay(333); analogWrite(PORT_G, 0);
  analogWrite(PORT_B, 255); delay(334); analogWrite(PORT_B, 0);
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.println("loop()");
  uint8_t r, g, b;
  if (ReadRGB(r, g, b))
  {
    analogWrite(PORT_R, r);
    analogWrite(PORT_G, g);
    analogWrite(PORT_B, b);
    Serial.println(r);
    Serial.println(g);
    Serial.println(b);
  }
}

bool ReadRGB(uint8_t &r, uint8_t &g, uint8_t &b)
{
  if (ReadLine(buffer, LENGTH))
  {
    Serial.println("ReadRGB() read a line.");
    int i = sscanf(buffer, "%d,%d,%d", &r, &g, &b);
    return i == 3;  // Notify whether 3 integers were successfully read.
  }
  return false;
}

int ReadLine(char *buffer, const int length)
{
  static int index = 0;
  int last_index = 0;
  int ch = Serial.read();
  if (ch > 0)
  {
    switch(ch)
    {
      case '\r':
        break;
      case '\n':
        last_index = index;
        index = 0;
        return last_index;
      default:
        if (index < length - 1)
        {
          buffer[index++] = ch;
          buffer[index] = 0;
        }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send 3 bytes over serial, which is typically very low bandwidth, you really should just send 3 bytes rather than the ASCII representations, along with commas and newlines. If you send:

```
255,255,255
```

with a newline at the end, you are actually sending 12 bytes instead of the 3 you need.

Say you have 3 variables, `a`, `b` and `c` you want to send:

```
a, b, c = 1, 8, 255
```

you can pack them as 3 unsigned bytes (`B`) like this:

```
import struct

packet = struct.pack('3B',a,b,c)
```

Then if you check the contents, you will see your 3 bytes:

```
b'\x01\x08\xff'
```